# Facebook login button with 'Continue as {Name}' for Next.js 13

Tags: facebook, next.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, next.js13

Is there a way to implement the official Facebook login button with the user's profile picture and the 'Continue as John' feature in Next.js 13?

Everything I found so far is deprecated, using old versions of React and causing hydration errors plus they don't have the official button.

Something like @react-oauth/google that provides the official Google button

I tried react-facebook, react-facebook-login and a few others but never got the result I wanted. The only place I found the button was the Facebook developers site and they only support vanilla JS as far as I saw